# workflow email not sending with sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I installed sharepoint 2013 foundation successfully .. now I want to create Workflow with multi approval using sharepoint designer but when I created workflow i had a problem with sending email I got (The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing email settings for the server are configured correctly) .. I already have Exchange server installed wnsc.sd

Comment: you need to configure outgoing settings in central admin

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up **"Configure outgoing e-mail settings"** under System Settings in Central Administrator?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up Outgoint e-mail setting in central admin
[image]